# Calling C# from C++, difficulties with "." in C# namespace

Tags: c#, c++, com

First off, I'll admit I'm cargo-culting this a little bit -- my nice clean sample code doesn't work when I'm wedging it into the real world.  That being said...

I have a DLL called CPierce.CSharpCall.dll that has something like the following C# in it:

```
namespace CPierce.CSharpBridge
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("3D08DF02-EFBA-4A65-AD84-B08ADEADBEEF")]
    public interface ICSide
    {
        // interface definition omitted...
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("CBC04D81-398B-4B03-A3D1-C6D5DEADBEEF")]
    public partial class CSide : ICSide
    {
        // class definition omitted...
    }
}
```

This is registered with `regasm /tlb`, etc.. Then, my C++ code looks something like this:

```
#import "CPierce.CSharpCall.tlb" named_guids

    // Contains syntax errors!
int myfunc()
{
    HRESULT hRes = S_OK;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    CPierce.CSharpBridge::ICSide *pManagedInterface = NULL;

    hRes = CoCreateInstance(
            CPierce.CSharpBridge::CLSID_Class1, 
            NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
            CPierce.CSharpBridge::ICSide, 
            reinterpret_cast<void**> (&pManagedInterface));

    // Calls to the interface omitted....

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, of course, the syntactically wrong bit about **`CPierce.CSharpBridge`**.  I know in C++ if I want to have a similar namespace to the C# code I could say:

```
namespace CPierce
{
    namespace CSharpBridge
    {
        // definitions go here
    }
}
```

But I don't think that's what I'm looking for here, since I just need to refer to two constants that are in another namespace without putting the entire method in that namespace.

What *is* the C++ syntax I need to complete this call to `CoCreateInstance`?

---

Update: On deeper (much deeper) inspection, I'm finding that my .tlb file created by regasm is nearly empty.  When I catenated all of my source into a single .cs file and compile with:

```
csc /debug /t:library BigFile.cs 
regasm BigFile.dll /tlb:BigFile.tlb
```

I get a hefty (and useful) tlb file.

When I compile the whole project from Visual Studio, I'm getting a .DLL all right, but regasm doesn't do anything with it but produce a minimal .tlb file.  (ildasm shows almost no differences between the two DLL's)

If I compile BigFile.cs in Visual Studio, I get a DLL that's also useless.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you tried using `::` instead of `.`?

Comment: Yeah.  Something weird though... If I click on the .tlb in the object browser this lists as CPierce_CSharpBridge.  Now, CPierce_CSharpBridge::ICSide comes back as "ICSide is not a member of PR1_CSharpBridge".  Not solved, but different anyway.

Comment: Does it work if you *don't* have a nested namespace?

Comment: My problems may be a little deeper, the .tlb file has almost nothing in it -- I'm not sure my types/interfaces are being registered completely.  regasm is not giving errors, but I'm not getting a useful .tlb out of it.  I have a default constructor... time to look at regasm closer.

Comment: For me "." was replaced by "_" when generating the tlb with regasm. Simply opening the tlb file with Visual Studio showed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem on the C#/Visual Studio side.  I'll abandon this question and open an appropriate one.  Thank you for your help in narrowing it down.

Answer (score 3):

C++ doesn't use the `.` operator to delimit namespaces; it uses `::`. You would use `CPierce::CSharpBridge` instead of `CPierce.CSharpBridge`. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to help you because you don't know what namespace is actually being generated by the TLB.

A simple solution to that is to not use namespaces at all and import without them:

```
#import "CPierce.CSharpCall.tlb" named_guids no_namespace
```

Comment: Actaully, changing it to use `CPierce.CSharpBridge::ICSide` gives me the errors `CPierce` is not a class or namespace name.  Sorry, I tried that too.

Comment: @clintp: `CPierce::CSharpBridge::ICSide`.

Comment: yeah, sorry, that's what I meant to type.  All colons, still an error.

Comment: @clintp: Are you fine with ignoring the namespaces?

Comment: @clintp - Update your question and post what you are using currently and the exact compile error you recieve.  I assume the dll is in a location and you are linking to it the correct way, you don't seem to need that much help.